# How create several elements in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, python, django, d3.js

In my django project I have 3 connected with each other models. `GROUP -> TASK -> FUNCTION`. I am tring to create tree with the help of `D3.js` library. The problem is my current code show me only first element of Group model. How to show other elements? Is it possible in `D3.js`?

[image]

**models.py:**

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=250)

class Task(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=250)

class Function(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=250)
```

**template**:

```
var treeData = [
   {% for group in groups %}
   {
   "name": "{{ group }}",
   "parent": "null",
   "children": [
      {% for task in group.task_set.all %}
      {
      "name": "{{ task }}",
      "parent": "{{ group }}",
      "children": [
         {% for function in task.function_set.all %}
         {
            "name": "{{ function }}",
            "parent": "{{ task }}"
         }{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}
         {% endfor %}
      ]
      }{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
  ]
 }{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
];
```

Comment: I highly suggest doing this logic in your view. Use `json.dumps` to convert the dictionary to something that javascript can use, then render it in your template as `var treeData = {{your_var|safe}};`. It's much faster to do your logic in the view, and it helps maintain the idea that your view handles logic and your template handles HTML.

Comment: ok, how create such dynamic dictionary (treeData) in view?

Comment: @user2896976 So do you have any ideas?

Comment: In your python view just create a variable `treeData = {}` and then do your loops and conditions there, and send it to the template as part of the context when you call `render`.

Comment: I tried to do as you said but when I tried to put loops inside treeData = {} it raise error in my PyCharm. Can you show me how to make it correctly?

Comment: Can you edit your post with the python code you wrote